# library not found for -lRNPDFView

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-pdf and I have also run

`react-native link react-native-pdf`

Is there any way to link it manually for iOS?

Comment: Have u searched this on google? You will get a lot of answers on manually linking libraries in IOS. In fact, there is a react-native page , check http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#linking-libraries